# is there any alternative for session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

is there any other way to save our data
in session when we save data dos not mater what is the type of it
save:

```
Session["instauser"] = _instaApi;
```

use:

```
var IInstaApi = Session["instauser"] as InstaApi
```

i know for save in db or file we should serialized the data but i cant.
because the InstaApi contain

> HttpClient , HttpClientHandeler ,...

Is there any thing like session?
but keep data in db or file, not memory like session.

**Update**

That is private instagram api we create instant of it and login with it(no mater how!) and then if we could save that object (instants of InstaApi ) then we can use it for ever no need to login again

Comment: You are misusing the `Session` object, do not use it like a static all-purpose container, it is really designed only to contain *session* data (as small as possible). That's why you have problems in persisting those objects.

Comment: @Federico Dipuma
 its work fine but i dont want to use **Session**

Comment: You'll never successfully serialize a complex object that contains `HttpClient , HttpClientHandler`

Comment: You can use Global Cache which also keeps data in memory

Comment: It would be good if you be more specific about what exactly you want to achieve? Why you want to store HttpClient and Handler in session? Why not store simple details in sessions and use them later to create HttpClient ?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the `InstaApi` object alive between visits? Storing anything in Session is (for me) a bad idea. It breaks the concept of statelessness and does not scale when you want to use more than one webserver.

Comment: What I was saying is that you really should store the *parameters* of that API you are talking about, and not an `HttpClient` or whatever big object you are using at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If its purpose is for use within controller and view of MVC, other alternatives are `ViewBag, ViewData and TempData`.

`ViewBag` and `ViewData` life is only for one request, while `TempData` can be persisted.

Comment: This seems to answer a question that wasn't asked by OP. If you're speculating, clear it up with a question in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at APC_STORE,  unlike many other mechanisms in PHP, variables stored using apc_store() will persist between requests.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php